# what does typescript syntax "<SomeClass>" as a parameter mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was reading angular2 code and I found some confusing syntax for me.
The full code is below.(from https://github.com/domfarolino/angular2-login-seed)

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
//import { Control } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

/**
 * Import interfaces that service depends on
 */
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor (private http: Http, @Inject('apiBase') private _apiBase: string) {

    }

    private _loginApi = this._apiBase + '/authorize/local';
    private _logoutApi = this._apiBase + '/logout';
    private _authenticatedApi = this._apiBase + '/api/authenticated';
    private _registerApi = this._apiBase + '/api/users/register';
    private _userExistsApi = this._apiBase + '/api/users/exists';

    login(user) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(user);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http.post(this._loginApi, body, <RequestOptionsArgs> {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
                        .map((res: Response) => res)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    authenticated() {
        return this.http.get(this._authenticatedApi, <RequestOptionsArgs> {withCredentials: true})
                        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    logout() {
        return this.http.get(this._logoutApi, <RequestOptionsArgs> {withCredentials: true})
                        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    register(user) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(user);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http.post(this._registerApi, body, <RequestOptionsArgs> {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
                        .map((res: Response) => res)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getUsers() {
        return this.http.get(this._apiBase + "/api/users?limit=5&desc=true", <RequestOptionsArgs> {withCredentials: true})
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getMe() {
        return this.http.get(this._apiBase + '/api/users/me/', <RequestOptionsArgs> {withCredentials: true})
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json().me)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
    }
}
```

and I can't find out what below code as a parameter means.

```
<RequestOptionsArgs> {headers: headers, withCredentials: true}
```

Is there anyone can give me an idea?

Comment: Basically, it is casted to that type.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble because I didn't know what keyword I should use to google about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `<Type> variable` is a cast. See [Type Assertions on the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

It shows two examples, it is possible to cast using:

```
<string> somevar
```

and also with

```
somevar as string
```

> The two samples are equivalent. Using one over the other is mostly a choice of preference; however, when using TypeScript with JSX, only as-style assertions are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

class is work as a datatype here . .. 
  Ex .

Class student {
Name : String , 
RollNo: Number 
}

now if i declare a variable

Public Students:Obect

Now i can push in students with a object having name and roll no.